# C# wait for thread to finish without blocking UI

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

```
        checkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => CheckTokens()));
        checkerThread.Start();

        // Re-enable controls when done
        stopCheckButton.Visible = false;
        stopCheckButton.Enabled = false;
        startCheckButton.Enabled = true;
        loadTokenListButton.Enabled = true;
        exportTokensButton.Enabled = true;
        clearCheckButton.Enabled = true;
        clearValidButton.Enabled = true;
        tokenInputBox.Enabled = true;
```

When the thread is running controls are disabled in my Form. I want to re-enable them when the thread is done. How would I do that without blocking the UI by `thread.Join()`?

Comment: Have you heard about async/await?

Comment: Yes, but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Trust me, you should use async await. If you don't know about them learn about them. They are especially intuitive in these kinds of UI driven scenarios and work beautifully with winforms.

Comment: using async / await depends on the type of work that must be done imo.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is in the toolbox, you'll like its RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: It may not always be appropriate, but `await Task.Run(CheckTokens)` is a very nice option and it would seem to me

Comment: Remember - "await" can be like a virus: it can "infect" unrelated parts of your code base with stupid "Async" declarations.

Comment: @paulsm4 No, it would only affect *related* parts of the code base, namely anything that cares about performing an action when the asynchronous operation is finished.  And that problem isn't specific to `async` as a keyword, it's inherent in the operation being asynchronous, which is necessary to not block the UI, even if you use some other form of asynchrony.

Comment: @paulsm4 it certainly can be something that spreads, but it may well be worth it. That said, in this case it looks like event handler code which means `async void` so I doubt that's a concern here

Answer (score -1):

I suggest consider using a [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7)

EXAMPLE CODE:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-run-an-operation-in-the-background?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Here's another example:

> https://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet
>
> ```
> public Class Form1
>
>     Public Class ArgumentType
>         Public _a As Int32
>         Public _b As Int32
>     End Class
>
>     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>         ' Create the argument object.
>         Dim args As ArgumentType = New ArgumentType()
>         args._a = 5
>         args._b = 6
>         ' Start up the BackgroundWorker1.
>         ' ... Pass argument object to it.
>         BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(args)
>     End Sub
>
>     Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
>                                          ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
>                                          Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
>         ' Do some time-consuming work on this thread.
>         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
>         ' Get argument.
>         Dim args As ArgumentType = e.Argument
>         ' Return value based on the argument.
>         e.Result = args._a * args._b
>     End Sub
>
>     Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
>                                                      ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
>                                                      Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
>         ' Called when the BackgroundWorker is completed.
>         MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString())
>     End Sub
> End Class
> ```

Comment: @Janic - as  Frederik Gheysels said, "using async / await depends on the type of work that must be done imo".  I think BackgroudWorker is probably better suited for your needs.  Q: You said "C#" in your title... but VB.Net in your tags.  Which is it?  Both examples should easily translate to either language :)

Comment: @Janic if you are going to learn something, don't learn obsolete backgroundworker. Learn async/await.

Comment: @paulsm4 `await` is a *more* generalized tool than BGW.  `await` can do everything a BGW can do, a BGW can't do everything `await` can do.  You'd only solve the problem with `await` differently than awaiting a single call to `Task.Run` if it were a problem *that BGW isn't suitable for at all*.

Comment: @Janic - I believe "newer" isn't necessarily "better".  BackgroundWorker is perfectly appropriate here.  And "await" CAN be like a virus: it can "infect" unrelated parts of your code base with otherwise unnecessary "Async" declarations.  Please consider "upvoting" and/or "accepting" this reply if it helps.